# Помогите решить задачу js желательно с пояснением

Tags: javascript

1. Создайте HTML-файл, в теле которого будет один тег - `<p>"Привет"</p>`
2. Напишите скрипт, который при клике на надписи, будет изменять её текст на "Пока!".

Comment: ну пока вы не помочь просите, а решить за вас

Comment: google в помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div onClick = "change()" id="helloDiv">Hello</div>    
    <script>    
let change = (helloDiv) => {
document.getElementById("helloDiv").innerHTML = "Пока"
}           
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если уж строчный онклик, здесь можно `<div onClick="this.textContent = 'Пока!'">Hello</div>` без всякого id ) Или если добавлять id - легче уже начать писать всё прямо в скрипте... `document.getElementById("helloDiv").onclick = function(){ this.textContent = "Пока"; }`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME если уж человек спрашивает как сделать такую задачу, то мне кажется не стоит писать с использованием this - для начального понимания будет сложновато